# Producto cartesiano de dos tablas muestra el error: la subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas #nombre y #apellido, querría hacer un producto cartesiano de todas las posibilidades e insertarlas en una nueva tabla que se llama *combinacion*.

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
insert into combinacion
values ((select row_number() over (order by nombre) as orden from #nombre n, #apellido a1, #apellido a2),
        (select nombre from #nombre n, #apellido a1, #apellido a2),
        (select a1.apellido + ' ' + a2.apellido from #nombre n, #apellido a1, #apellido a2));
```

Pero me da este error:

> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto
> cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza
> como expresión.

Comment: Hi there, you are at [es.so]. Please translate your question to spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Te invito a leer [ask], a realizar el [tour] y a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La construcción que utilizas no es válida.

Si quieres insertar los datos del producto cartesiando en la tabla, no incluyas una cláusula `values` como parte del insert, sino inserta directamente los resultados del select (que debiera ser solo uno, y no tres), con una sentencia `insert`/`select`.

En este caso, si no incluyes una lista de campos, el `select` debe devolver el mismo número de campos y en el orden en que están creados en la tabla.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que la tabla `combinacion` tiene tres columnas que serían (más o menos) `id`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, esto debiera funcionar:

```
insert into combinacion
select   row_number() over (order by n.nombre, a1.apellido, a2.apellido) as orden
       , nombre
       , a1.apellido + ' ' + a2.apellido
  from #nombre n
       cross join #apellido a1
       cross join #apellido a2;
```

Como notarás, he cambiado además la vieja sintaxis `from tabla1, tabla2, tabla3` por `from tabla1 cross join tabla2 cross join tabla3`, que hace lo mismo, pero deja clara su intención, y que existe en el estándar desde 1992 y está soportada en SQL Server probablemente desde el 2000.

Comment: Entiendo muy bien y funciona para mi perfectamente muchisimas gracias

Comment: @AyoubNadir acabo de fijarme que era SQL Server y no MySQL. Mil disculpas